# Glance image create stuck in SAVING status

Tags: openstack

I am using the Glance HTTP API (v1 & v2) to create an image.  These latest tests are against v2.

I am passing in a url via headers 'x-glance-api-copy-from' (and have also tried 'x-glance-api-copy-from') for an image:  http://10.x.x.x/ub14.raw

The command returns a 201 with a status of "queued", but a follow up call to get the image information shows status as 'SAVING' and progress of 25.

Another user can successfully create an image from the command line with the same copy-from url.

I have tried several different JSON payloads to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Are you on devstack? g-api (glance-api) log will show you the error. Glance-api fetches the image from the url and then saves it to the configured backend.

- First: find out where the logs are, it depends of deployment type. In devstack there's local.conf option SCREEN_LOGDIR=/opt/stack/logs
- Second: grep glance-api log for a "Traceback".

I assume this may be related to proxy settings / load balancer. Cannot say more without knowing the deployment topology.